# How to trigger UpdatePanel update from MasterPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, triggers, updatepanel

I have an `UpdatePanel` in a dynamically loaded `UserControl`, which is in a `TabPanel` of a `TabContainer`. Is it possible to specify in markup an `asp:LinkButton` in the `MasterPage` as an `UpdatePanel`s trigger?

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically add a `AsyncPostBackTrigger` or `PostBackTrigger`

Here is how can you do this:

```
AsyncPostBackTrigger apTrigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
apTrigger.ControlID = "LinkButtonId";
apTrigger.EventName = "Click";
((UpdatePanel)((TabPanel)TabContainID.FindControl("tabPanel")).FindControl("UpdatePanelID")).Triggers.Add(apTrigger);
```

**Edit:** If the control is in a Master Page then first you need to find the LinkButton.

```
LinkButton LinkButtonId = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("LinkButtonId");
apTrigger.ControlID = "LinkButtonId";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is that the trigger control is in the master page, so how can I just specify apTrigger.ControlID? Also, can't it be done in markup? Thanks.

Comment: But isn't ControlID a string? How can one assign a LinkButton to it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry add double qoute and check.

Comment: If we just use LinkButtonID, why do we need to find the control itself? And we come to the question I asked in my first comment.